# How much water should be added to a Maggi seasoning cube?

Tags: seasoning, bouillon, cubes

I sometimes use Maggi liquid seasoning in my cooking. My recipe calls for a specific number of grams to be added.

[image: Maggi liquid seasoning]

The other day, the supermarket was out of stock of the liquid seasoning, but they had these cubes:
[image]

Now my problem is, how do I add the right amount of seasoning to the recipe? There is no indication on the packaging, or advice on the internet that I can find.

How much water should one cube be dissolved in to make it the same concentration as the liquid seasoning?

Comment: recommended amount is usually written in the package as well

Comment: @Luciano - That's the first place I looked. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be and indication on the packaging of amounts.

Answer (score 5):

Maggi is a brand, produced by Nestle. It comprises several products, including Maggi brand liquid seasoning, Maggi brand instant noodles, and Maggi brand bouillon cubes.

These are different foods, not different forms of the same food. You cannot directly substitute one for another, and adding water to one will not make it like one of the others.

If you need a substitute for Maggi liquid seasoning, soy sauce (any variant other than "sweet soy sauce" or "dark Chinese soy sauce") will work decently well. You should roughly double the amount.

Comment: Thank you. I realise that that noodles are not a substitute for stock cubes. But Liquid Seasoning must be pretty close in function to powered seasoning cubes. My recipe calls for both Maggi liquid seasoning *and* soy sauce, so I can't use soy sauce as a substitute.

Comment: No, there's not much similarity, beyond the high level of glutamates and other products of proteolysis present in both. You're assuming way too much based on the brand name. Mix a bouillon cube with (hot) water and you get bouillon. Mix Maggi liquid seasoning with water and you get diluted Maggi liquid seasoning.

Comment: As for there already being soy sauce: Either add a bit more, or just ignore the Maggi. In some cuisines Maggi liquid seasoning tends to be added to any savory dish as a matter of course. If you know what you're looking for you could notice its absence, but it's never going to be the most important aspect of the flavor.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, they’re different products… but they both contribute a fair amount of salt.

So for that reason, I would recommend using an amount that is roughly equivalent in sodium.  It won’t be the same flavor exactly, but it will still add flavor.

- Maggi liquid seasoning is 330mg/tsp
- Maggi cubes are 1010mg/cube

So one cube has a much salt as 3 tsp (~15mL) of Maggi liquid.

Comment: Maggi liquid seasoning does have a fair amount of salt, but the salt isn’t really its primary flavor. Maybe it’s personal preference, but I think three teaspoons of Maggi would utterly take over a dish which could absorb a bouillon cube without incident.